# How do I make this repeat in C?

Tags: c, cs50

Just starting out and working through cs50. I want to:

1. prompt the user to input a number
2. count the number of digits in that number
3. if the number of digits is NOT equal to 13, 15, or 16:
   print "INVALID"
4. if "INVALID" repeat from step 1

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{

    long n = 0;

    n = get_long("Number: ");

    int i = 0;

    long cn = n;

    while (cn > 0)
    {
        cn = cn / 10;
        i++;
    }
    
    if (i != 13 && i != 15 && i != 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    }
}
```

This gets me through steps 1-3, but I cannot figure out how to get step 4 to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

One has to be careful about making assumptions. The leading digit(s) may be 0, and the number value may not reflect what was entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // for library function 'isdigit()'
#include "my_cs50.h" // my own library with its quirks

int main() {
    for( ;; ) { // infinite loop to avoid tedium
        char *ps = get_string( "Enter a number: " );

        int cnt = 0;
        while( isdigit( *ps ) ) {
            ps++;
            cnt++;
        }

        // my version of get_string() returns the trailing '\n'
        if( ( *ps == '\0' || *ps == '\n' )
        && ( cnt == 13 || cnt == 15 || cnt == 16 ) )
            ; // all good
        else
            printf( "INVALID\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1234567890123
Enter a number: 123456789012345
Enter a number: 1234567890123456
Enter a number: 12345678901234567
INVALID
Enter a number: 0000000000000
Enter a number: 0001112223334
Enter a number:
```

EDIT: Alternative version indicating how to continue processing with valid string of digits (and possible trailing '\n').

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> // for library function 'isdigit()'
#include "my_cs50.h" // my own library with its quirks

int check_format( char *ps ) { // return 0 for bad, 1 for good
    // THIS 'ps' is a local copy.
    // Same value, but not the same variable as in main().
    int cnt = 0;
    while( isdigit( *ps ) ) {
        ps++;
        cnt++;
    }

    // my version of get_string() returns the trailing '\n'
    return ( ( *ps == '\0' || *ps == '\n' )
        && ( cnt == 13 || cnt == 15 || cnt == 16 ) );
}


int main() {
    for( ;; ) {// infinite loop to avoid tedium
        char *ps = get_string( "Enter a number: " );

        if( !check_format( ps ) ) {
            printf( "INVALID\n" );
            continue; // or something else???
        }

        /* perhaps more processing with validated string */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And, then again, one can make use of standard C library functions, too...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // for library function 'strspn()'
#include "my_cs50.h" // my own library with its quirks

int main() {
    for( ;; ) { // infinite loop to avoid tedium
        char *ps = get_string( "Enter a number: " );

        int cnt = strspn( ps, "0123456789" );

        // my version of get_string() returns the trailing '\n'
        if( ( ps[ cnt ] == '\0' || ps[ cnt ] == '\n' )
        && ( cnt == 13 || cnt == 15 || cnt == 16 ) )
            ; // all good
        else
            printf( "INVALID\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Warning: It's a mistake to rush off to convert some digits to an integer value. That is setting foot on a path you'll have to abandon in order to make progress.

Comment: Interesting, and good thought on the leading zeros. CS50 uses `strtol()` in its conversion for `get_long()` with a with a base of `10`, so leading zeros are automatically discarded. (see [cs50.c line 364](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/main/src/cs50.c)) Nothing wrong with doing it manually either. Only issue here is there is no `long` left over for use after the length check is done.

Comment: No stated requirement for having a `long` after this validation. The OP used `main()` so I did too. Put the "string validation" into a function passed the start of the string, and return a go/no-go,, and no damage done. :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Alternative version posted.

Comment: That is a lot of good effort. I like to see a good range of answers provided so the questioner has to sit back and scratch his head and think "how do all these work to do the same thing?" -- that's when learning occurs.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Having previously seen this CS50 challenge on SO, the next subtask is performing a checksum on the digits... left to right... (parity is important). Leaping into conversion to a value puts on blinkers and sets the tone for later heartache and head scratching.

Comment: Oh how true. Tunnel vision leads to a great many questions on SO. Knowing multiple ways to *skin-the-cat* in C helps avoid that. Having a bit of foresight into the next subtask is like having an ace in the hole... Priceless.

Comment: Note for CS50 users who are not yet familiar with the `char *` data type used in this answer: As you will learn in week 4 of CS50, that data type is equivalent to the `string` data type of the CS50 library.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel and CS50 users: Do not form the habit of 'hiding' pointer types by using `typedef {datatype}* someterm;` as has been done with the CS50 `string` datatype, Pointers (and pointers-to-pointers) are a difficult concept for beginners, and MANY of the cries for help on SO come from those who've not understood how to use pointers successfully. Face the challenge and master the understanding. You will need it. In the future, you will be writing in 'C', not relying on CS50...

Answer (score 3):

Even simpler, loop continaully and use the `snprintf (NULL, 0, ...)` trick to determine the number of digits. Break only if the number of digits is correct.

From `man 3 snprintf`

> The functions `snprintf()` and `vsnprintf()` do not write more than
> size bytes (including the terminating null byte (`'\0'`)).  If the
> output was truncated due to this limit, then the return value is the
> number of characters  (excluding  the  terminating  null byte) which
> would have been written to the final string if enough space had been
> available.

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
   
  long n = 0;
  
  for (;;) {            /* loop continually */
    int ndigits = 0;
  
    n = get_long("Number: ");
  
    ndigits = snprintf (NULL, 0, "%ld", n);
    
    if (n < 0) {        /* subtract 1 for '-' sign */
      ndigits -= 1;
    }
    
    if (ndigits == 13 || ndigits == 15 || ndigits == 16) {
      break;            /* break loop only if ndigits correct */
    }
    
    puts ("INVALID");
  }
}
```

(**note:** technically `'-'` isn't a digit, so you need to account for negative values)

**Example Use/Output**

```
./bin/ndigitstest
Number: 1
INVALID
Number: 123456789012
INVALID
Number: 1234567890123
```

Or, with negative values,

```
$ ./bin/ndigitstest
Number: -123456789012
INVALID
Number: -1234567890123
```

and so on...

Comment: And if "000001234567890123" is entered?? or "    1234567890123"?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Yep, don't know if that is desired or not, but the internals of `get_long()` handle discarding the leading `0`s. So if that isn't desired, then using `get_long()` to begin with is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is that you give a flag to check input is invalid or not. For example,

```
int invalid = 1;
long n = 0;

while (invalid) {
    n = get_long("Number: ");
    int i = 0;
    long cn = n;

    while (cn > 0)
    {
        cn = cn / 10;
        i++;
    }

    if (i != 13 && i != 15 && i != 16)
    {
        printf("INVALID\n");
    } else {
        invalid = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the specific part in a while(1) loop. So here is the solution:

```c
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    long n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    long cn;
    while(1)
    {
        i=0;
         n = get_long("Number: ");
         cn = n;
        while (cn > 0)
        {
            cn = cn / 10;
            i++;
        }
       
        if (i != 13 && i != 15 && i != 16)
        {
            printf("INVALID\n");
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```